# IE Compatibility Mode : does the "edge" mode enforce the user settings?

Tags: internet-explorer, ie8-compatibility-mode

I would like to know if the "edge" mode, set in the web page for Internet Explorer, enforces the user setting (if this user has set a compatibility mode).

For exemple :

1) In my web page :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

2) In the user browser, for example Internet Explorer 8, the user set the compatibility mode to IE7.

What happens now if the user visits my web page? Which setting is considered? The webpage setting or the user setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compatibility mode is fully explained by this diagram for IE9:

http://ieblog.members.winisp.net/misc/How%20IE9%20Determines%20Document%20Mode.svg

Refer to it for a good understanding of this IE feature.

My question is answered. There are two cases of user settings :

1) The mode indicated by the dev tools overrides all existing settings, including the X-UA-Compatible tag.

2) The user setting in the "compatibility settings" window does not overrides the XUA-Compatible tag.

In the first case, the edge mode will not be applied.
In the second case, it will be effective.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after trying many combination I had this working 
note I have compatibility checked for intranet

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<head runat="server">
```

Answer (score 0):

The META tag takes priority UNLESS the user explicitly selects the compatability mode while on your page, then it reverts back. However again the tag takes priority first because IE assumes you as the programmer know what you are talking about.

Comment: So, if I understand you, in my example, the webpage will be displayed in IE7 compatibility mode, won't it ?